# Bounded gradient flow solutions without compact sublevel sets

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems, non-convex-optimization, gradient-flows

A standard result in the theory of dynamical systems states that for a continuous system $(*)$ defined by $\dot{x}(t) = F(x)$, where $ F : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ locally Lipschitz, if one finds a Lyapunov function, i.e. a continuously differentiable function $L : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is everywhere non-negative and has compact sublevel sets $ \mathcal{L}_K = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid L(x) \leq K \}, \forall K > 0 $ and is non-increasing along trajectories $x(t)$, then one can conclude that the said system has bounded solutions, i.e. for each initial condition $x_0$, there exists some constant $B>0$ such that $ \| x(t) \| \leq B $, where $x(t)$ is a solution of the system $(*)$ with $x(0) = x_0$.

I am interested in this result in the case of gradient flows; that is, when there exists some lower bounded function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F = - \nabla \phi$ and I would like to relax the assumption that the sublevel sets are bounded.

For example, one might look at the simple function $\phi(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2 $ which gives us the system $ \begin{bmatrix} \dot{x}_1(t) \\ \dot{x}_2(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 x_1(t) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ which has the solution $x_1(t) = x_1(0) e^{-2t}, x_2(t) = x_2(0)$ where $(x_1(0), x_2(0))$ are the initial conditions. We see that in this case $x_1(t) \to 0 $ as $t \to \infty$ and it's clear that whatever initial conditions we choose, we can bound the solution. Yet the sublevel sets of the Lyapunov function of the system (which in this case is the function itself) are not bounded, since for example $\mathcal{L}_1 = \{ (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x_1^2 \leq 1 \} = [-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R} $.

Of course, what I showed here is a quite special instance, since the function $\phi$ is convex. But one can easily imagine some non-convex functions where this still holds.

So my question is: for gradient flows, if one drops the assumption of compact sublevel sets, what other weaker, suitable assumptions could one impose to still obtain that the solutions remain bounded for any initial condition?

Any thoughts and references are welcome! Thank you!

Comment: You could just use LaSalle's invariance principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle). You just need to show that there is some set $D$ that is positively invariant (in this case some ball around the origin) and then the Lyapunov function you used is fine.

Comment: @dgadjov thanks for the reply! After briefly reading this, I don't think this would work. My understanding is that LaSalle's invariance principle only characterises the nature of the accumulation points of any trajectory (but in fact, it does not say anything regarding their existence) and the asymptotic stability of a fixed point (which again does not exclude the fact that the gradient flow might diverge when initialised at certain points); but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question, you originally asked about "assumptions could one impose to still obtain that the solutions remain bounded for any initial condition". LaSalle gives you a way of showing this. For your example, let $L = x_1^2 + x_2^2$ then any sublevel set $L_K$ is positively invariant (it is also compact). From LaSalle's we know it converges to the largest invariant subset of $L_K$, i.e., $E_K = \{(x_1,x_2) | |x_2| \leq K\}$. This shows that if we start in $L_K$ then we stay in $L_K$, i.e., it is bounded since $L_K$ is compact.

Comment: "assumptions could one impose to still obtain that the solutions remain bounded for any initial condition ... without compact sublevel sets"

Comment: The conclusion in your second comment works once we assume that the sublevel sets are compact (and forward invariant).

Comment: If you really want to go down this path then look at https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/29714/3/El-Hawwary_Mohamed_I_201106_PhD_thesis.pdf

In Section 2.2 they define stability and attractivity for non-compact sets. It has been a while since I have read this but this should give you a starting point.

Comment: @dgadjov I have a similar question: could we obtain the stability of an equilibrium over a set $D$ by saying that (1) $D$ is positive invariant (2) $V(x)$ is lower bounded and the derivative of $V$ along trajectories is strictly negative when $x\neq 0$ and being zero when $x=0$? Here I relaxed the condition of radially unboundedness (which implies the boundedness of $x$) to the condition (1), since the positive invariance property of $D$ would guarantee the boundedness of $x$. Would this be correct from your point of view? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can say that. Unfortunately, the Wikipedia version of LaSalle's isn't the greatest. In the book "Nonlinear System" by Khalil, LaSalle's theorem is stated in the following comment:

Comment: Let $\Omega \subset D$ be a compact set that is positively invariant. Let $V : D \to R$ be a continuous differentiable function such that $\dot{V} \leq 0$ in $\Omega$. Let $E$ be the set of all points in $\Omega$ where $\dot{V} = 0$. Let $M$ be the largest invariant set in $E$. Then every solution starting in $\Omega$ approaches $M$ as $t\to \infty$. Notice that we don't need $V$ to be positive definite, radially unbounded, or lower bounded. This is essentially the version of LaSalle you are looking for. Additionally, there are some corollaries changing the assumptions on $D$ and $V$.